# Creating Variable Name with Variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have something like this:

```
$CORSAIR_TYPE="good"
$CASE="CORSAIR"
...
$local temp_type=${CASE}_TYPE
echo ${!temp_type}
```

This gives me the value of the variable `CORSAIR_TYPE`, which is "good". Is there a way of doing this without creating the `temp_type` variable? What would I replace `echo ${!temp_type}` with?

Thanks

Comment: yes, `eval echo '$'"${CASE}_TYPE"` or something like that.

Comment: With `${!foo}`, `foo` has to be a variable.  So, no, at least with the code you've given, not really.  Also, there is no situation where I'd go with any `eval` solution just to avoid creating a single temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling across this post, this is one way I found of doing it:

```
echo $(eval echo $`echo ${CASE}_TYPE`)
```

Comment: All you need is `eval 'echo "$'${CASE}'_TYPE"'`